# Read block info from log

Tags: bitcoin-core

I'm new in the Bitcoin world, but I want do the script. The script will read "blocks" from debug.log, but now when I looking to a debug.log I don't see anything about blocks. Is it possible?

Here is example from my log:

> [D:2020-04-13T18:58:49Z] (mempool) Added 30e28c7a2ad288fa3457569423b388f43e0b874032dd14c8bfc1db49777c6746 to mempool (txs=3182).
> [D:2020-04-13T18:58:50Z] (net) Requesting 1/1 txs from peer with getdata (131.188.40.191:8333).
> [D:2020-04-13T18:58:50Z] (mempool) Added 0ee02ea46ea6c06a3c0addcf651612f8681272310f583f2bd3f273d0c14c3cf0 to mempool (txs=3183).
> [D:2020-04-13T18:58:50Z] (net) Requesting 6/6 txs from peer with getdata (194.15.231.236:8333).
> [D:2020-04-13T18:58:50Z] (mempool) Added 86e5a85abc674e432aeffef3876772ea8588dc2cdab79ed236041b8875a171e7 to mempool (txs=3184).
> [D:2020-04-13T18:58:50Z] (mempool) Added fc5c9d831785b1e43b0f9adb4333d7ed23562b332a061f958f7f98dcd5397043 to mempool (txs=3185).
> [D:2020-04-13T18:58:50Z] (mempool) Added 5742cd2c1f376720596ee0256ca825b2940cf22b7b6e681c3666b46fb72fe144 to mempool (txs=3186).
> [D:2020-04-13T18:58:50Z] (mempool) Added e8222822f1fba4fb8dd4d2aa60e6d42b38f2ef35c98e09f81961d72c4502beb1 to mempool (txs=3187).
> [D:2020-04-13T18:58:50Z] (mempool) Added 123d121ec06bf8cfaeefb5ba25ed303fa82ee75e8179452cfb4be80d7cfd7161 to mempool (txs=3188).
> [D:2020-04-13T18:58:50Z] (mempool) Added 59b40a817ffc223361ec07874abb889d0769c8bb6155cb6cdf175680221a0f77 to mempool (txs=3189).

Comment: What is "the script"?

Comment: debug.log is just a software level log; you should not rely on it for any serious data, as it offers no actual way to verify anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **when I looking to a debug.log I don't see anything about blocks. Is it possible?**

I expect the `net` category of log information should contain entries relating to the exchange of blocks with peers but I would not expect the full block data to be logged.

The name of the debug log suggests it is mainly intended as a way to investigate problems, and not intended as a means to routinely extract block data. You should use the RPC API for that.

---

Related

- [What are the debug categories?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/66892/13866)
- [API reference (JSON-RPC)](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC))
- [getblock](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.20.0/rpc/blockchain/getblock/)