# Are there any existing tools to measure the time required for block and transaction validation？

Tags: bitcoin-core

The validation time of transactions and blocks has a great impact on the performance of the Bitcoin network. Are there any special measuring tools that can be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitcoin Core has inbuilt benchmarks which can be enabled using `debug=bench`, which breaks down the validation time of incoming blocks.

Comment: How to enable "debug=bench" please?

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/66892/13866 and https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.20.0#notable-changes