# Do you need a configuration flag to be able to obtain detailed debug logs?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, debugging, logging

Do you need to configure Bitcoin Core with `--enable-debug` to be able to obtain [detailed debug logs](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/66892/what-are-the-debug-categories) when running bitcoind with `-debug=category`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they are orthogonal. `--enable-debug` creates unoptimized binaries which are more usable when you're trying to attach a debugger (e.g. gdb, lldb). It is unrelated to debug output. Debug output is controlled at runtime using `-debug=X` flags.

Thanks to the individuals who answered this on IRC.

Comment: Just a small elaboration on `--enable-debug`: it also enables more runtime checking. If all you need is the ability to run a debugger, consider specifying `./configure CXXFLAGS='-O0 -g3'`.